# Can't get the documents with dynamic document ID in query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to get the data from specific document from firestore.
database have First collection named "learner" and in each document of this another collection "request".
(each document is created with the same name as email)
so each document have emails as their name.

when im using a static address i get the correct response .
but of course the addressing i need to get is with the email which user will input,

```
Firestore.instance.collection("/learner/Qwr4@g.com/requests/").snapshots().listen(Elements);
```

Elements is the function which converts the response into a list

using this function i get correct response 
but what i need is

this is what is need.
this function is giving me list of 0 length

```
void function(String email) { Firestore.instance.collection("learner").document(email).collection("requests").snapshots().listen(Elements); }
```

Comment: It looks good to me. Are you sure that you implemented both of these in the same way and that the email you pass as a parameter is correct?

Comment: yeaH man..i did it <